# Python Paho MQTT client not instantiated

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I want to follow the example mentioned [here](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/) to connect to a broker in Python. The code is just stuck at the instantiation part. No response, no nothing ! What could be wrong ?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
>>> c = mqtt.Client("random")
```

The `mqtt.Client` doesn't ever complete. Since the connect method is yet to be called, I am not sure, if this could be a network issue. Nevertheless, a `Ctrl-C` shows the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py",     line 422, in __init__
self._sockpairR, self._sockpairW = _socketpair_compat()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 271, in _socketpair_compat
    sock2, address = listensock.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 202, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

This happens with `python3` too.

**UPDATE**: This issue happens on the Raspberry Pi. On Ubuntu, the same code works fine.

Comment: Does your PI have IPv4 networking enabled, and a valid localhost hostname?

Comment: Well am getting a valid ip address. Also Python Mosquitto client works well.

Comment: Does `ping localhost` on the PI work fine? Mosquitto Python is obsolete.

Comment: No. Ping didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like networking (`sock`) not properly configured. Did you test your Raspberry Pi networking?

Test that you receive answers from: `ping 8.8.8.8`

Test dns with: `ping www.google.com`

Check that you have a valid gateway with: `ip route show`

Check in your `/etc/resolv.conf` that there are valid entries like:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Try also to call Client method without arguments or with all of them:

```
c = mqtt.Client()

c = mqtt.Client(client_id="123456789", clean_session=True, userdata=None, protocol=MQTTv311)
```

Comment: All of the above check out correctly. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue - running `client.py` (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/`) manually it would hand up at:

```
271     sock2, address = listensock.accept()
```

ping localhost would fail (or would ping some host out on the internet, `localhost.home.net` ;)   Turns out I had `127.0.0.1 localhost`  commented out in `/etc/hosts`:

```
 #127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Once I removed the hash it started working OK.